# Moving from tokenizer to substring

Tags: java, substring, tokenize

I have this program working with tokenizer, but i was wondering how can i do this using substring.

what Im trying to do is have the user enter 14 numbers/characters.
and i want to get the input 1 by 1.

with the tokenizer the user have to input like this "1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D 5 E 6 F 7 G"
with space in between each number/character for the tokenizer to work.

What i want to do with substring is to make it so my user can input like "1A2B3C4D5E6F7G"

```
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the work hours");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

    while (x < 7) {

        if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        startday[x] = st.nextToken();
        endday[x] = st.nextToken();

        }

        x++;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to proceed character by character, why not `charAt()`?

Comment: wow why did i not think of that.
thank you lol

Comment: `char[] singlechars = string.toCharArray();`

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can simply loop through the internal char array:

```
str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the work hours");
for (char entry:str.toCharArray()) {
  processValue(entry);
}
```

Or, to allow optional spaces:

```
str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the work hours");
for (char entry:str.toCharArray()) {
  if (entry != ' ') {
    processValue(entry);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the whitespaces with regex from the resulting string when you're using tokens.

Using `substring` for something like that isn't very efficient, in my opinion. But if you really need to do it that way, [read here.](http://javacodeonline.blogspot.ro/2010/12/java-substring-examples.html)